# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}x^k=\frac{1}{2}$ where $x=\frac{1}{3}e^{-1/3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, closed-form

How to prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}x^k=\frac{1}{2}, ~\text{where}~~ x=\frac{1}{3}e^{-1/3}~?
$$
I found this sum in my notes, but I don't remember where I got it. Any hints or references would be nice.

Comment: A generalization: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}\big(\frac{1}{ae^a}\big)^k=\frac{1}{a-1}$

Comment: @NilotpalSinha it seems you are right. Can you prove it?

Comment: @NilotpalSinha It should be  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}\big(\frac{1}{ae^{1/a}}\big)^k=\frac{1}{a-1}$ (note the exponent $1/a$ ).

Comment: It might be easier to prove the above generalization by summing over a or integrating over a and using some sort of nice exchange of summation or differentiation or something.

Comment: @Asvin - You are right, typpo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idea, too long for a comment: use the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
$$W(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n,$$
$$W'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n^n}{n!}x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^n}{n!}(-x)^{n-1}$$
$$\cdots$$

Comment: Note that you have solved the problem since $$W'(x)=\frac{W(x)}{x+xW(x)}$$ so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{n}}{n!}x^{n}=-\frac{W(-x)}{1+W(-x)}.$$ Taking $x=e^{-1/3}/3$ we can conclude since $$-\frac{W(-e^{-1/3}/3)}{1+W(-e^{-1/3}/3)}=\frac{1/3}{1-1/3}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: this proves also the general claim from the comments (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k}{k!}\big(\frac{1}{ae^{1/a}}\big)^k=\frac{1}{a-1}$ for $a > 1$ (as in the question).

Then $\frac{1}{a-1} = - 1+ \frac{1}{1-1/a} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac1a)^k$ by the geometric series. So one has to show

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\Big[-1 + \frac{k^k}{k!}{e^{-k/a}}\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^k=0$

Writing some terms

$0 = \Big[-1 + {e^{-1/a}}\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big) + \Big[-1 + \frac{2^2}{2!}{e^{-2/a}}\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^2 + \Big[-1 + \frac{3^3}{3!}{e^{-3/a}}\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^3 + \cdots$

Expanding the exponentials and writing the terms up to $(1/a)^3$, say,  requires to take the  terms

$0 = \Big[-\frac{1}{a} + \frac12 (\frac{1}{a})^2 + \cdots \Big](\frac{1}{a}\big) + \Big[-1 + \frac{2^2}{2!}(1-\frac{2}{a} + \cdots)\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^2 + \Big[-1 + \frac{3^3}{3!}(1 + \cdots)\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^3 + \cdots$

Sorting for powers of $1/a$ gives

$0 = \Big[0 \Big](\frac{1}{a}\big) + \Big[-1 -1 + \frac{2^2}{2!}\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^2 + \Big[\frac12 - 2 \frac{2^2}{2!} -1 + \frac{3^3}{3!}\Big](\frac{1}{a}\big)^3 + \cdots$

and all the prefactors are zero, as required. The full solution then comes upon expanding all exponentials. Clearly this requires some more formal work.